# How to get the remote host in a JSF app with SSO login

Tags: jsf, single-sign-on

My web app is deployed in a network which uses Oracle Access Manager 10g Single sign On(SSO) for identity management.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context
                .getExternalContext().getRequest();
String remoteHost = request.getRemoteHost();
String remoteAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

The above code does not give in the correct user's ip address nor computer name when integrated with SSO instead gives in the server url as remoteHost.

Could someone please let me know how to find user's identical ip address and remoteHost in JSF with SSO.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Oracle Access Manager SSO specifically, but any SSO solution for web applications usually involves the application server sitting behind an SSO server that acts as a proxy for the user.  It intercepts the request, injects the user credential information into the request header, and then forwards the modified request information to the application server.  This effectively hides the IP address of the user from the application server.

The good news is that most web based SSO software can be configured to include the original IP address of the user in the request header.  You should talk to the SSO server administrator and see if he can enable this functionality for your application.